# Intent filter support for multiple hosts with same path

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, deep-linking, applinks

My app should be available for deep-linking and does support multiple hosts (with same path). How is this possible without duplicating all path entries?

Example:

```
<data android:pathPattern="myPath1" android:host="myDomain1" android:scheme="https" />
<data android:pathPattern="myPath1" android:host="myDomain2" android:scheme="https" />
```

I don't like this solution since all app links must be duplicated (just to support different domains).

The host just differs in the domain ending, e.g. `www.mydomain.*`, but as far as I've read the attribute `android:host` does only support the asterisk as first character of the host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that in one `<data>`.

As you already mentioned, the wildcard for the host attribute is limited to subdomains, so you can't use it in your case.

You have no choice other than to use multiple `<data>` with the same path but different hosts.

Though, if your path pattern is complex enough you could use `android:host="*"` and basically catch all hosts. But with that you would risk clashes with other domains.